# callback not working in a draggable list with list.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, list.js

Im trying to create a draggable list with list.js but when I try to edit, add or delete an item nothing happen, I guess is something with the callbacks but I cant find the solution.

this is my html:

```
<script src="http://listjs.com/assets/javascripts/list.min.js"></script>
 <div id="contacts">
  <ul id="sortable">
<li class="id">
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/1" class="img" >
   <h3>The Grasslands</h3>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .</p>
    <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
     <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button>     </td>
</li>

  <li class="id">
   <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/2" class="img" >
     <h3>Paradise Found</h3>
       <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
    <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
</li>

 <li class="id">
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/3" class="img" >
    <h3 >Smoke On The Water</h3>
     <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
    <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
</li>

<li class="id">
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/4" class="img" >
  <h3>Headline</h3>
  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <td class="edit"><button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button></td>
    <td class="remove"><button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button></td>
</li>
</ul>
<table>
<td class="img">
  <input type="hidden" id="id-field" />
  <input type="text" id="img-field" placeholder="Img" />
</td>
<td class="description">
  <input type="text" id="description-field" placeholder="Description" />
</td>
<td class="add">
  <button id="add-btn">Add</button>
  <button id="edit-btn">Edit</button>
 </td>
 </table>
 </div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
/*sortable */
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

/* listjs */

var options = {
valueNames: [ 'id', 'description', 'img', ]
};

// Init list
var contactList = new Sortable('contacts', options);

var idField = $('#id-field'),
descriptionField = $('#description-field'),
imgField = $('#img-field'),
addBtn = $('#add-btn'),
editBtn = $('#edit-btn').hide(),
removeBtns = $('.remove-item-btn'),
editBtns = $('.edit-item-btn');

// Sets callbacks to the buttons in the list
refreshCallbacks();

addBtn.click(function() {
contactList.add({
id: Math.floor(Math.random()*110000),
description: descriptionField.val(),
img: imgField.val(),

});
clearFields();
refreshCallbacks();
});

editBtn.click(function() {
var item = contactList.get('id', idField.val())[0];
item.values({
id:idField.val(),
description: descriptionField.val(),
img: imgField.val(),
});
clearFields();
editBtn.hide();
addBtn.show();
});

function refreshCallbacks() {
// Needed to add new buttons to jQuery-extended object
removeBtns = $(removeBtns.selector);
editBtns = $(editBtns.selector);

removeBtns.click(function() {
var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
contactList.remove('id', itemId);
});

editBtns.click(function() {
var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
var itemValues = contactList.get('id', itemId)[0].values();
idField.val(itemValues.id);
descriptionField.val(itemValues.description);
imgField.val(itemValues.img);

editBtn.show();
addBtn.hide();
});
}

function clearFields() {
descriptionField.val('');
imgField.val('');
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: No, I dont have any console error

Comment: Really? I keep getting an error *ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined* on the line `var contactList = new Sortable('contacts', options);` See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/1/ Maybe it should be `new List();` ?

Comment: This example does not generate any errors: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used listjs, so I do not know if this is what you're trying to do. I did find the following: http://listjs.com/examples/add-get-remove/

From that and your example, I built this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="contacts">
  <ul id="sortable" class="list">
    <li class="id">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/" class="img">
      <h3 class="title">The Grasslands</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .</p>
      <td class="edit">
        <button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td class="remove">
        <button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </li>

    <li class="id">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/" class="img">
      <h3 class="title">Paradise Found</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <td class="edit">
        <button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td class="remove">
        <button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </li>

    <li class="id">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3/" class="img">
      <h3 class="title">Smoke On The Water</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <td class="edit">
        <button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td class="remove">
        <button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </li>

    <li class="id">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4/" class="img">
      <h3 class="title">Headline</h3>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <td class="edit">
        <button class="edit-item-btn">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td class="remove">
        <button class="remove-item-btn">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <table>
    <td class="img">
      <input type="hidden" id="id-field" />
      <input type="text" id="img-field" placeholder="Img" />
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <input type="text" id="title-field" placeholder="Title" />
    </td>
    <td class="description">
      <input type="text" id="description-field" placeholder="Description" />
    </td>
    <td class="add">
      <button id="add-btn">Add</button>
      <button id="edit-btn">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.list .img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.list .title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list .description {
  font-size: 0.65em;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*sortable */
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable().disableSelection();
});

/* listjs */
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', 'title', 'description', 'img', ]
};

// Init list
var contactList = new List('contacts', options);

var idField = $('#id-field'),
  titleField = $("#titleField"),
  descriptionField = $('#description-field'),
  imgField = $('#img-field'),
  addBtn = $('#add-btn'),
  editBtn = $('#edit-btn').hide(),
  removeBtns = $('.remove-item-btn'),
  editBtns = $('.edit-item-btn'),
  sortList = $("#sortable");

// Sets callbacks to the buttons in the list
refreshCallbacks();

addBtn.click(function() {
  contactList.add({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 110000),
    description: descriptionField.val(),
    img: imgField.val(),

  });
  clearFields();
  refreshCallbacks();
  sortList.sortable("refresh");
});

editBtn.click(function() {
  var item = contactList.get('id', idField.val())[0];
  item.values({
    id: idField.val(),
    description: descriptionField.val(),
    img: imgField.val(),
  });
  clearFields();
  editBtn.hide();
  addBtn.show();
});

function refreshCallbacks() {
  // Needed to add new buttons to jQuery-extended object
  removeBtns = $(removeBtns.selector);
  editBtns = $(editBtns.selector);

  removeBtns.click(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
    contactList.remove('id', itemId);
  });

  editBtns.click(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
    var itemValues = contactList.get('id', itemId)[0].values();
    idField.val(itemValues.id);
    descriptionField.val(itemValues.description);
    imgField.val(itemValues.img);

    editBtn.show();
    addBtn.hide();
  });
}

function clearFields() {
  descriptionField.val('');
  imgField.val('');
}
```

It allows you to sort the list and add items. Since an item is being added dynamically, `$("#sortable").sortable("refresh");` should be called when items are added.

Hope that helps.

**Update 1**

I found a number of little issues and tinkered with the styling more for jQuery UI. Play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/11/

**JavaScript**

```
/* listjs */
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', {
    attr: 'src',
    name: 'img'
  }, 'title', 'description']
};

// Init list
var contactList = new List('contacts', options);

var idField = $('#id-field'),
  titleField = $("#title-field"),
  descriptionField = $('#description-field'),
  imgField = $('#img-field'),
  addBtn = $('#add-btn'),
  editBtn = $('#edit-btn').hide(),
  removeBtns = $('.remove-item-btn'),
  editBtns = $('.edit-item-btn'),
  sortList = $("#sortable");

// Sets callbacks to the buttons in the list
refreshCallbacks();

addBtn.click(function() {
  contactList.add({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 110000),
    title: titleField.val(),
    description: descriptionField.val(),
    img: imgField.val()
  });
  clearFields();
  refreshCallbacks();
  sortList.sortable("refresh");
});

editBtn.click(function() {
  var item = contactList.get('id', idField.val())[0];
  item.values({
    id: idField.val(),
    title: titleField.val(),
    description: descriptionField.val(),
    img: imgField.val(),
  });
  clearFields();
  editBtn.hide();
  addBtn.show();
});

function refreshCallbacks() {
  // Needed to add new buttons to jQuery-extended object
  console.log("Callback selectors: ", removeBtns.attr("class"), editBtns.attr("class"));
  removeBtns = $("." + removeBtns.attr("class"));
  editBtns = $("." + editBtns.attr("class"));

  removeBtns.click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
    contactList.remove('id', itemId);
  });

  editBtns.click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var itemId = $(this).closest('li').find('.id').text();
    var itemValues = contactList.get('id', itemId)[0].values();
    idField.val(itemValues.id);
    titleField.val(itemValues.title);
    descriptionField.val(itemValues.description);
    imgField.val(itemValues.img);

    editBtn.show();
    addBtn.hide();
  });
}

function clearFields() {
  titleField.val("");
  descriptionField.val("");
  imgField.val("");
}

/*sortable */
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable().disableSelection();
  $(".edit-item-btn").button({
    icon: "ui-icon-comment",
    showLabel: false
  });
  $(".remove-item-btn").button({
    icon: "ui-icon-close",
    showLabel: false
  });
  $(".buttons").controlgroup();
  $('#search-field').on('keyup', function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    contactList.search(searchString);
  });
});
```

I did a lot of little things, as you can see, one is fixing the use of `.selector`. I switched to `.attr("class")` to get the class name and used it as a class selector. This works since the element only has 1 class defined. Might hunt around to see if there is better solution.

This is used in `refreshCallbacks()` like so:

```
// Needed to add new buttons to jQuery-extended object
removeBtns = $("." + removeBtns.attr("class"));
editBtns = $("." + editBtns.attr("class"));
```

This function just re-assigns all the elements (in case any new ones were created) back to the variable. This fixed the issue with "Edit" and "Remove" buttons. I noticed edits were not capturing the Image Source url. I found that here: http://listjs.com/examples/data-attributes-custom-attributes/ So to fix it in your project, we do:

```
var options = {
  valueNames: ['id', {
    attr: 'src',
    name: 'img'
  }, 'title', 'description']
};
```

That I think will do you well.

**Update 2**

I spoke too soon.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/12/

The `id` was not being read, so edits would always pull up the first item. Fixed by updating the `li` with a `data-id` attribute. I had to go in and repair some of the jQuery to line up with this.

**Update 3**

Found another add, when sorting, the order is changed. When this happens, the List Index needs to be updated. Simple fix:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  update: function(e, ui) {
    contactList.reIndex();
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7LhmaLb/18/

Comment: Hey twisty thanks for your reply.. I checked your findle but the edit and remove button doesnt work.. I think Im missing something in editbn function but I dont know what.

Comment: I saw that too and have been tweaking it for a bit. Following the example from listjs site, and what I know, they should work to populate each of the fields below and they just are not. Investigating some more.

Comment: @DanielBlanco the problem lies here: *The `.selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting `.live()` in the jQuery Migrate plugin.* I'm using 3.1.1 in my fiddle. What version of jQuery will be used for your project?

Comment: @DanielBlanco fixed and I may write a bug report for listjs... will update my answer.

Comment: thanks again I didnt notice.. I think the last update is working good but I notice that when you add a new item and try to delete it isnt possible.. any ideas about that? @Twisty

Comment: I just check this, thank you so much.. I have trying to add some code to make a localstorage but Isnt working.. what do you think is the best way?

Comment: @Ultimated I do not know or understand your question. I would advise you to google it, see what you find and if needed create a new question.

Comment: I did it.. I tagged you in that question.

Comment: @Ultimated I don't see it anyplace.

Comment: This http://codepen.io/danultimate/pen/VpMQjR I just want to save the last state of the list with localStorage @Twisty

Comment: Ok, I would advise populating this detail in the `create` callback, to capture the list as is and also in the `update` callback so it then is updated after any update to the order.